# Parsing array in JSON string using MiniJSON

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I have this JSON string:

```
{"person":[{"age":"0","name":"John"}]}
```

"person" is a list and can contain more people than just John.

Using MiniJSON, how can I read all the people in "person" ?

What I'm trying:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = MiniJSON.Json.Deserialize(jsonString) as Dictionary<string, object>;
List<object> list = (List<object>)(dict["person"]);
Dictionary<string, string> character = list[0] as Dictionary<string, string>;
print(character["name"]);
```

But it says character["name"] is a null reference.

Comment: My guess is that character being cast to Dictioanry<string, string>; is coalescing to null.  Try Dictionary<string, object> character = list[0] as Dictionary<string, object>; instead.

Comment: Worked as charm, @MichaelG! Feel free to use it as answer. Although it's strange that it works as Dictionary<string, object> when i print `(string) character["name"]`

Comment: A `Dictionary<string,string>` is *not* a `Dictionary<string,object>`. Casting one to the other will fail. This means that `list[0] as Dictionary<string, string>` will return a `null`

Comment: @Daniel why did you specify `object` in the first place? Why not specify the types explicitly? You wouldn't need to cast.

Comment: Don't know about using `dynamic` yet, nor it's allowed on C# version I'm using, but I was just following a tutorial in the internet when this error came.

Answer (score 1):

Deserializing this JSON returns something like this structure (generated via [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/)):

```
public class Person
{
    public List<PersonElement> PersonList { get; set; }
}

public class PersonElement
{
    public long Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I don't think you can just cast that into a `Dictionary<string,object>`, hence the null pointer. Try adding a breakpoint and look at the result of the deserialization to see if you can just cast it or if you need to iterate over the result to feed it into a dictionary (if you want to use a dict).

Comment: In fact I could, the main problem was that I was trying to parse directly to Dictionary<object, string> instead of Dictionary<object, object>.

Comment: @Daniel that's why you got a null. That cast would fail. An inheritance relation between type arguments doesn't translate to an inheritance relation between the dictionaries